# Match words that don't start with a certain letter using regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am learning regex but have not been able to find the right regex in python for selecting characters that start with a particular alphabet.

Example below

```
text='this is a test'
match=re.findall('(?!t)\w*',text)

# match returns
['his', '', 'is', '', 'a', '', 'est', '']

match=re.findall('[^t]\w+',text)

# match
['his', ' is', ' a', ' test']
```

Expected : `['is','a']`

Comment: Try: https://regex101.com/r/OzUEO9/1

Comment: `[i for i in text.split() if i[0] != 't']`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### With regex

Use the negative set `[^\Wt]` to match any alphanumeric character that is not *t*. To avoid matching subsets of words, add the word boundary metacharacter, `\b`, at the beginning of your pattern.

Also, do not forget that you should use raw strings for regex patterns.

```
import re

text = 'this is a test'
match = re.findall(r'\b[^\Wt]\w*', text)

print(match) # prints: ['is', 'a']
```

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/I9CaiZ/1).

### Without regex

Note that this is also achievable without regex.

```
text = 'this is a test'
match = [word for word in text.split() if not word.startswith('t')]

print(match) # prints: ['is', 'a']
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost on the right track. You just forgot `\b` (word boundary) token:

```
\b(?!t)\w+
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/YyLZwr/1)

Comment: Thanks .Actually match=re.findall(r'\b(?!t)\w+',text) worked. It was looking for raw string